# Keras - Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (256, 1, 5)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I've seen the other questions with similar issues to mine, but none of them solved my issue. I'm building a neural network which repeatedly takes in 256 images of size (600,600,2) during training, but I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (256, 1, 5)
```

Here's the model architecture:

```
    self.policy_model = Sequential()
    self.policy_model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', data_format = "channels_last", input_shape = (600, 600, 2)))
    self.policy_model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    self.policy_model.add(Conv2D(96, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    self.policy_model.add(Flatten())
    self.policy_model.add(Dense(16, activation = "relu"))
    self.policy_model.add(Dense(5, activation = "softmax"))
    self.policy_model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

Comment: try change the line `self.policy_model.add(Dense(16, activation = "relu"))` to `self.policy_model.add(Dense((16,), activation = "relu"))`

Comment: What's your train_label (`train_y`) shape? I suppose that it's (256, 1, 5) where `batch_size=256`. You should reshape your train label to be (256, 5). You can simple use numpy `reshape` method for converting each label's shape from `(1, 5)` to `(5,)`. Hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: @bit01 that fixed it for me, thanks